# Shouldn't Infinite Past be smaller than all other dates?

Tags: date-and-time

Max of <kbd>Infinite past</kbd> and a finite time gives <kbd>Infinite past</kbd>.

```
Max[DateObject[{-\[Infinity],1,1},"Day"],DateObject[{2023,7,1},"Day"]]
```

> DateObject[{-[Infinity], 1, 1}, "Day"]

This doesn't make sense, this is breaking my code. This has to be a bug?

Comment: what is the semantics of applying `Max` on DateObjects? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 7):

I think the biggest problem with `Max` here is that it doesn't produce an error message or return unevaluated. It is intended to compare strictly numerical values.

Correct function for dates is `MaxDate`:

```
MaxDate[{InfinitePast, DateObject[{2023, 7, 1}, "Day"]}]

(* DateObject[{2023, 7, 1}, "Day"] *)
```